# Problem about variation of red-black trees

Tags: binary-trees, red-black-trees

I got an exercise about a variation of RB trees but I am struggling to see how to solve it, therefore I'll be happy to hear your opinion about it.
The exercise is:

> Let us define a binary search tree which we will call Red-Red-Black tree if it satisfies the following:
>
> 1. Every node is either red or black.
> 2. Every leaf (NIL) is black.
> 3. If a node is red, and its parent is red as well then both its children are black.
> 4. For each node, all paths from the node to descendant leaves contain the same number of black nodes.
>
> Find the largest possible number of internal nodes in Red-Red-Black tree with N nodes, such that their black height is $k$ find also what is the smallest possible number.

I was trying to think what I can deduce about the possible height of a node when I know its black height $k$.
So because of property number 3, we know that after each black node in the path we can have at most 2 consecutive red nodes, so I was wondering if I can say that the biggest possible height of a node that has a black height of $k$ is at most $3k$ and then try to figure out the cases about the possible level in the tree of nodes that has black height $k$ (Another observation which I am not sure about is: when we have a node which is not the root and this node has a black-height of $k$ then the siblings of this node must have the same black-height).
I will appreciate any clues. Thanks

Comment: "Every leaf (NIL) is black." Are leaves counted toward "N nodes"? Is there any internal node NIL?

Comment: Where did you encounter this exercise?  Please credit the original source for all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @JohnL. I think NIL leaves are not counted toward "N nodes".

Comment: @D.W. Actually I translated this question from Hebrew to English but I don't mind giving a reference to it.
Here is the question :
https://mega.nz/folder/0Sg0iD4B#0OPF1JJgFjtYoJuStlsCtA/file/IGYT1aKY
(Page 29, First question)
There is also a solution in English to those questions but it seems like the guy who wrote the solution answered a different question, so maybe this question is just poorly worded.
The solution I am talking about can be found here :
https://mega.nz/folder/0Sg0iD4B#0OPF1JJgFjtYoJuStlsCtA/file/IOZj0CCB